# Adding try-catch block for injected byte code through ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to inject byte code using ASM, I want to surround the injected byte code with a try-catch block. However, I get a VerifyError on onMethodExit : "Inconsistent stack height 0 != 1".

When the try-catch block is removed it works as expected.  Any pointer is highly appreciated.

Here is my code snapshot:-----

```
 protected void onMethodEnter()  {    

        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_0);
        mv.visitVarInsn(ISTORE, okFlag);

        Label startTryBlock = new Label();
        Label endTryBlock = new Label();
        Label startCatchBlock = new Label();

        // Initialization try-catch block
        mv.visitTryCatchBlock(startTryBlock, endTryBlock, startCatchBlock, "java/lang/Exception");

        // starting try block
        mv.visitLabel(startTryBlock);

        mv.visitLdcInsn(className);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(description);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "org/sam/agent/trace/RootTracer", "allMethodBegin", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z");
        mv.visitVarInsn(ISTORE, okFlag);

        //ending try  block
        mv.visitLabel(endTryBlock); 
        Label endCatchBlock = new Label();
        mv.visitJumpInsn(GOTO, endCatchBlock);

        // start catch block
        mv.visitLabel(startCatchBlock);
        mv.visitVarInsn(ASTORE, isStatic);

        //ending catch block
        mv.visitLabel(endCatchBlock);
}



private void onMethodExit(int opcode)  {

        Label startTryBlock = new Label();
        Label endTryBlock = new Label();
        Label startCatchBlock = new Label();

        // Initialization try-catch block
        mv.visitTryCatchBlock(startTryBlock, endTryBlock, startCatchBlock, "java/lang/Exception");

        // starting try block
        mv.visitLabel(startTryBlock);

        if(opcode == ATHROW){
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP);
            mv.visitLdcInsn(className);
            mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
            mv.visitLdcInsn(description);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "org/sam/agent/trace/RootTracer", "recordException", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        }
        mv.visitLdcInsn(className);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(description);
        mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, okFlag);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(opcode);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "org/sam/agent/trace/RootTracer", "MethodEnd", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZI)V");

        // ending try block
        mv.visitLabel(endTryBlock); 
        Label endCatchBlock = new Label();
        mv.visitJumpInsn(GOTO, endCatchBlock);

        // starting catch block
        mv.visitLabel(startCatchBlock);
        mv.visitVarInsn(ASTORE, isStatic); // FAILED Here

        // ending catch block
        mv.visitLabel(endCatchBlock);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Any Java method is executed on an operand stack. During its execution, values are pushed onto or popped from the stack. When using a jump instruction as you do in your `onMethodExit(int)`-emitted method, you need to make sure that there are the exact same **types of elements** on the operand stack for any **target of a jump instruction**. These element types need to be the same, independently from the path through the code from where this target of a jump instruction was reached. This seems not to be the case for your code. One code path seems to reach a jump instruction target with one element on the operand stack, another path reached the same target statement with zero elements on the stack. Thus the complaint of an `Inconsistent stack height 0 != 1`.

The problem is most likely related to:

```
mv.visitJumpInsn(GOTO, endCatchBlock);
```

I assume that the verifier complains that your exception block completes with the exception reference on the stack when the `finally` block is reached. This is not the case for the path where no exception is thrown.

Try removing the line

```
mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP);
```

from within your `if` statement such that the operand stack always contains zero elements. I assume that you let ASM compute the stack map frames for you.